# Using SVG font in <mask>

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file that was generated by Illustrator that I have modified slightly, so that I can use it as a mask on both Webkit and Gecko.

The file has the glyphs I need stored in `<font>` with a defined font-family. Right after  there is a `<text>` element. This is what Webkit uses directly to create the mask. The font-family value correlates to the defined font and it renders correctly.

Then I have a `<mask>` element (because Firefox can only use that) with the same `<text>` element inside of it. It renders, but for some reason the font-family that is being declared won't work. I feel like this is something simple but I have very little experience with SVG (though now I know a hell of a lot more than I did!)

Basically how do I get the element inside mask to be able to reach the `<font>` element?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not support SVG fonts. Convert the SVG font to a woff font by using something like [this](http://onlinefontconverter.com/).

Comment: This worked like a charm. For people curious, you can use the `<style>` element inside the SVG file and call an external WOFF file.